# Where can I download previous version of itunes?

Tags: itunes

I am looking to download previous version of iTunes (iTunes 10.2.2). When I tried googling, all the webpages direct to apple site which has only the update iTune 10.3 for download.

Can any one let me know, how can I get older version of iTunes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to find older versions of iTunes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378386/where-to-find-older-versions-of-itunes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://appldnld.apple.com/iTunes10/041-0533.20110418.AqP4r/iTunes10.2.2.dmg) link.