# Where to find older versions of iTunes?

Tags: itunes, mac, windows

Where can I find a version of iTunes older than 12.7 for Mac or Windows?

I have both a Windows 10 PC and a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave.

Comment: What macOS are you on? 12.6.5 is a special version which still has the App Store, but won't run on Mojave or later. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079

Comment: I am on macOS Mojave. I also have a Windows PC, could you install a version of iTunes where you can manage apps on that? My PC is on Windows 10.

Comment: Why have you listed iOS and iPhone in tags? Also, [edit] the question to clarify about windows and Mojave.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have also found a version of iTunes which might do the job, I will report back whether it works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download links for some of the older versions of iTunes are available here:

https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes

iTunes 12.6.2 for macOS, iTunes 12.4.3 for Windows 64-bit are the latest under 12.7 listed.